# What is the correct nomenclature for expressing a genotype where a recombination event may occur?

Tags: genetics, nomenclature, recombination

Given an example punnett square:

```
 ------------------------- 
 | x   | A-b     | Y     |
 ------------------------- 
 | a-B | A-b/a-B | a-B/Y |
 ------------------------- 
 | A-b | A-b/A-b | A-b/Y |
 ------------------------- 
 | a-b | A-b/a-b | a-b/Y |
 -------------------------
```

What is the correct nomenclature to express the genotype prior to putting it into a punnett square? The parent's genotype looks like *a-B/A-b x A-b/Y* except I want to show that a recombination event can occur, yielding the third row in the punnett square table.

This is relation to my [previous](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/98336/using-punnett-squares-to-express-sex-gene-linkage-and-recombination-frequency) question about how to calculate recombination frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "genotype".

A Punnett square is a visualization technique to help us think, it doesn't change the terminology.

If what you mean is the 1N genotypes represented in the rows/columns that combine to make the 2N genotypes, you might consider "[haplotype](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/haplotype-haplotypes-142/#:%7E:text=A%20haplotype%20is%20a%20group,genetic%20makeup%20of%20an%20organism.)" (haploid genotype). The haploid cells with those genotypes might be called [gametes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamete), but that refers to the cell and not to the genotype.

If you are specifically interested in those genotypes/haplotypes in which a recombination event has occurred (or not), you could call them recombinants or non-recombinants. In some cases you can encounter specialized terminology, for example in [yeast tetrad analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrad_(meiosis)) you encounter terms such as "tetratype", "nonparental ditype", "parental ditype". But those are not generally used outside the yeast field, I believe.